# Enable/disable Quick Launch and Tree View with PowerShell for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, navigation, pnp-powershell, current-navigation

There are many [links](http://bexgordon.com/2014/10/set-current-navigationquick-launch-and-global-navigation-with-csom/) that shows how to change the settings for Global and Current navigation and we can use `Get-PnPNavigationNode` to modify the navigation nodes for the Quick Launch but I can't find anything that enable/disable the Quick Launch and Tree View under Navigation Elements. Is it possible with SharePoint PnP/CSOM?

Image attached for clarification[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline "https://site-url/"
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$web.QuickLaunchEnabled = $true
$web.TreeViewEnabled = $true
$web.Update()
# Execute-PnPQuery is working now, but is being deprecated, so use Invoke-PnPQuery
# Execute-PnPQuery
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, why didn't I try the simplest thing first. Had a look here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpnavigationnode?view=sharepoint-ps and didn't see anything regarding it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Gautam, this worked. It is strange that even defining the template to not use the quicklaunch, it was always enabled by default