# Enable Tree View Navigation using Power Shell script

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

I want to enable tree view navigation in a site collection and sub site level using power shell. Power shell script loop through site collection and all sub sites and turn on Enable Tree View Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the script below to do enable Tree View

```
 connect-pnponline http://siteurl -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 $web = Get-PnPWeb
 $web.QuickLaunchEnabled = $true
 $web.TreeViewEnabled = $true
 $web.Update()
 $subWebs=Get-PnpSubWebs -Recurse
 foreach ($sub in $subWebs)
 {
    $sub.QuickLaunchEnabled = $true
    $sub.TreeViewEnabled = $true
    $sub.Update()
 }
 Invoke-PnPQuery
```

It is using Pnp so you may need to [install it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) first.

Reference:[Enable/disable Quick Launch and Tree View with PowerShell for SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242332/enable-disable-quick-launch-and-tree-view-with-powershell-for-sharepoint-online)

Comment: i am running power shell using the CSOM.. can i get the code in power shell online

Comment: @Liz SharePoint Patterns and Practices (PnP) commands use CSOM and can work against both SharePoint Online as SharePoint On-Premises. I assume you want to use it in SharePoint Online Management Shell? Then install the Pnp first. Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline